# WPF DataGrid ItemsSource - Change from ComboBox

Tags: wpf, datagrid, combobox

Here is a snippet of XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding UnileverDataSet.Tables, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="5" x:Name="TableNameComboBox">
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TableName}"></TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>
                <DataGrid Margin="5" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding UnileverDataSet.Tables[TableNameComboBox.SelectedIndex]}"
```

UnileverDataSet is a `DataSet` made up of about 12 `DataTable`s

The idea here is that when the `ComboBox` value changes, the `DataGrid` should update based on the index value from the `ComboBox`.

Is this possible or should I look at another way of doing this?

If I do: `UnileverDataSet.Tables[0]`, then all works and data displays correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do element binding with combobox..

Your combox will display list of items in the  "UnileverDataSet.Tables" collection. When ever your select a item in Combo box the selected item will bounded to the Datagrid Items source (since we are using element binding)

Here is the sample code

```
<DataGrid Margin="5" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem,ElementName=TableNameComboBox}">
```

Comment: I want the grid to be bound to a table in a DataSet, and when the ComboBox changes value, update the Grid to use the table specified at the index of the ComboBox, does that make sense? I know this can be done in the code behind, something like DataGrid.ItemsSource = DataSet.Tables[TableNameComboBox.SelectedIndex], but wanted to do it in xaml.

Comment: I have added comments to my answer which will explain how it works. i am 100% sure that element binding will do work in your case

Comment: Looks as though it should work but the grid is not updated :S